# How can i make a itemtemplate or something with lable number in gridview coulm that Rate from 1 to 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sorting, gridview

## Solved Thanks for the Help guys :)

Hello guys i have an table of players and i want to rate it from 1 to 5 thats mean that i want to put numbers 1 to 5 at the coulms Pictures:
[Here You can see the Pictrue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCcaP.png)

I want to make a number from 1 to 5 that will write the numbers at the gridview like the picture up...

My Codes for now:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
    </asp:TemplateField>here

void PopulateGridView()
{
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter sqlDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT SoccerAchievements.PlayerCode, SoccerAchievements.TeamCode, Players.Players, Teams.Teams, SoccerAchievements.Achievement, SoccerAchievements.ID FROM ((Players INNER JOIN SoccerAchievements ON Players.ID = SoccerAchievements.PlayerCode) INNER JOIN Teams ON Players.TeamCode = Teams.ID AND SoccerAchievements.TeamCode = Teams.ID) ORDER BY [Achievement] DESC", sqlCon);
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    }
    if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        BestSoccerPlayers.DataSource = dtbl;
        BestSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
        BestSoccerPlayers.DataSource = dtbl;
        BestSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
        BestSoccerPlayers.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        BestSoccerPlayers.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        BestSoccerPlayers.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dtbl.Columns.Count;
        BestSoccerPlayers.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found";
        BestSoccerPlayers.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    }
```

Can any one help me please? I know its easy but i dont know how to do it...

Comment: you can simply take one template field and take label inside item template and just Text='<%#Eval("rateVal")%'> which retrieved from datarow.

Comment: Why not sort datatable : dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<string>("Column Name")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Okay i will try Thanks

Comment: shalin its not worknig for me bro

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text = '<% Eval ("rateVal") %>'/>

Comment: i wrote it good?

Comment: What do you mean jdwend how can i do it?

Comment: In the ItemTemplate use `<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>`